# Hibernate's mappings-based table creation isn't working: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jdbc

I had a lot of struggle with SQL scripts. Finally, I [got](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76059973/how-do-i-correctly-specify-the-directory-of-my-sql-scripts) them working fine. Then, out of pure interest, I dropped the tables and tried Hibernate's default schema creation (based on `@Entity` mappings)

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
-- I'll omit the population part to make it more MRE-ish
-- spring.sql.init.mode=always
-- spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:/sql/data.sql
```

Here's what I got

```
2023-04-20T06:02:20.227+03:00  WARN 1196 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table users (id bigint not null auto_increment, age tinyint not null, department varchar(255) not null, email varchar(255), enabled tinyint not null, last_name varchar(255) not null, name varchar(255) not null, password varchar(255) not null, salary integer, username varchar(255) not null, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table users (id bigint not null auto_increment, age tinyint not null, department varchar(255) not null, email varchar(255), enabled tinyint not null, last_name varchar(255) not null, name varchar(255) not null, password varchar(255) not null, salary integer, username varchar(255) not null, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
    at

-- I'll skip a ton of presumably unhelpful lines to make it more MRE-ish

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

**Why is that, and how do I avoid this error when choosing to rely on Hibernate's default schema creation?** As you may have noticed no FKs were created by Hibernate's SQL statement (not explicitly, at least). Here are my `@Entity` classes:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String department;
    @Column
    private int salary;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private byte age;
    @Column
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
    private byte enabledByte;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "role", referencedColumnName = "role")})
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<Role> authorities;
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "role", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String authority;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authorities")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<User> userList;
```

I recall I executed this statement in my Workbench ([here's why](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/326033/how-do-i-change-the-definition-of-a-primary-key-column-thats-involved-in-a-botc))

```sql
set foreign_key_checks=0;
```

It may be relevant

Just so you know, I read these questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55544341/how-to-fix-java-sql-sqlexception-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-when-crea), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58343760/spring-data-jpa-hibernate-java-sql-sqlexception-cannot-add-foreign-key-constra), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538617/hibernate-4-annotation-mysql-configuration-error-java-sql-sqlexception-canno), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64718737/caused-by-java-sql-sqlexception-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792243/spring-boot-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)) that mention the same exception. They don't appear helpful